# $x^2+3x+3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{25}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, finite-rings

> Give an example of an irreducible non-linear polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{25}[x]$.

I know that $x^2+3x+3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{25}[x]$ but I know no shorter proof then the exhaustive search (since $\mathbb{F}_{25}[x]$ is not a factorial ring we cannot use Eisenstein's criterion).

Can you please help me to find a more elegant idea?

Comment: Rabin's irreducibility test might be helpful. You can read more on it in this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343450/how-can-i-prove-irreducibility-of-polynomial-over-a-finite-field) and on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Rabin.27s_test_of_irreducibility).

Comment: The ring *is* “factorial”. The problem is that you have no primes to use Eisenstein's criterion with, because the base ring is a field.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a solution of $x^2-2=0$ in $\Bbb{F}_{25}$, then  [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2744985/11619) explains why $2+\alpha$ is a generator of the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_{25}$. It follows that $2+\alpha$ cannot be a square of another element of $\Bbb{F}_{25}$, so
$$x^2-(2+\alpha)$$
has no zeros in $\Bbb{F}_{25}$ and is thus irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_{25}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadratic formula works very well in any non-characteristic-$2$ field. So the roots of your $x^2+3x+3$ are
$$
\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{3^2 - 4\cdot 1\cdot 3}}{2\cdot 1} = 1\pm3\sqrt2
$$
Since $\Bbb F_{25}$ is a quadratic extension of $\Bbb F_5$, it contains all the square roots of any element in $\Bbb F_5$. So $\sqrt 2$ actually exists in $\Bbb F_{25}$, and your polynomial has roots. In fact, we get that *any* quadratic polynomial over $\Bbb F_5$ has roots in $\Bbb F_{25}$. So in order to find irreducible quadratics, you need to use at least one of the twenty non-$\Bbb F_5$ elements of $\Bbb F_{25}$.

For instance, we could take $x^2 + \sqrt2$. There is no square root to $\sqrt2$ in $\Bbb F_{25}$ (proof below), so this is irreducible.

> All elements in $\Bbb F_{25}$ may be written in a unique way as $a + b\sqrt2$, where $a, b\in \Bbb F_5$. If $\sqrt2$ has a square root in $\Bbb F_{25}$, then we have a solution to
>   $$
> (a + b\sqrt2)^2 = \sqrt2\\
> a^2 + 2b^2 + 2ab\sqrt2 = \sqrt2\\
> a^2 + 2b^2 = 0\quad\land\quad 2ab = 1
> $$
>   The only solution in $\Bbb F_5$ to $a^2 + 2b^2 = 0$ is $a = b = 0$, but that doesn't solve $2ab = 1$, so $\sqrt{\sqrt2}$ doesn't exist in $\Bbb F_{25}$.

Comment: Why does $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ contains all the square roots of any element of $\mathbb{F}_5$? Does every quadratic extensions contain all the square roots?

Comment: @MaximNikitin Yes. It is known that two Galois fields are isomorphic iff they have the same size. Since $\Bbb F_5(\sqrt2)$ and $\Bbb F_5(\sqrt3)$ both have $25$ elements, they are isomorphic, and in particular, they both contain a square root of $2$ and they both contain a square root of $3$. (In the particular case of $\Bbb F_5$, this is even easier to show. Since $-1 = 2^2$ already has a square root, and since $2 = -3$, we get that $2\sqrt2$ is a square root of $3$. So if an extension of $\Bbb F_5$ contains a square root of $2$ then it contains a square root of $3$, and vice versa.)

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial you're trying with is reducible, as others have already pointed out. Degree two polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_5$ don't work: they're *all* reducible in $\mathbb{F}_{25}[x]$.

What about a *cubic* polynomial? It's easy to test whether it's irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$: it just needs to have no root. So let' try the simplest one
$$
f(x)=x^3+x+1
$$
Then $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=3$, $f(2)=1$, $f(3)=1$, $f(4)=4$.

Can you see why this polynomial is also irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$?

Comment: Not really, can you please clarify, why?

Comment: This is a useful way of solving the actual question. @MaximNikitin Egreg's cubic has its roots in the degree three extension $\Bbb{F}_{125}$. Because $\gcd(3,2)=1$ it remains irreducible over the degree two extension $\Bbb{F}_{25}$. See for example [this oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/353233/11619).

Comment: @MaximNikitin The other comment gives a general hint, but you can also exploit being over a finite field. Let $K$ be an extension field where the polynomial has a root $r$. What’s the size of $\mathbb{F}_5(r)$?

Answer (score 2):

Your suggested polynomial $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F_5[X]$. Therefore $\Bbb F_5[X]/(f)$ is a quadratic extension of $\Bbb F_5$, hence *is* already $\Bbb F_{25}$, and by construction $f$ has a root there.